# Why i get stranger string when i send emoji character from iOS with nativescript

Tags: ios, node.js, nativescript, emoji, nativescript-vue

I work an app with Nativescript + Vuejs and Nodejs + MongoDB in the server side and have a trouble when i send emoji characteres from my iOS (12.1.4) to Nodejs server.

For example, when i send the emoji SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES (), i hope that string look like a **&#x1f60d** for can convert to an emoji and store on MongoDB

But get this string: **\M-p\M^_\M^X\M^M**

The most weird in this case is that it only happens when i send from my iOS 6 device.

With iOS 8 Emulator, the emoji send action works fine.

So, i really dont know what is the origin for this trouble, mayby my device or the keyboard config or the UTF ...

List of some emoji's strings that i get:

: \M-p\M^_\M^X\M^@

: \M-p\M^_\M^X\M^C

: \M-p\M^_\M^X\M^N

: \M-p\M^_\M^T\M-%

: \M-p\M^_\M^X\M-!

Some documentation:

http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/

https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Please give me some solution, or tell me what it my mistake.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoding code can be simplified to

```
extension String {
    func encode(_ s: String) -> String {
        let data = s.data(using: .nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)!
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

Note that it encodes all non-ASCII characters as \uNNNN, not only Emojis. Decoding is done by reversing the transformations:

```
extension String {
    func decode(_ s: String) -> String? {
        let data = s.data(using: .utf8)!
        return String(data: data, encoding: .nonLossyASCII)
    }
}
```

This returns an optional because it can fail for invalid input.

Example:

```
let s = "Hello ."
let e = encode(s)
print(e) // Hello \ud83d\ude03.

if let d = decode(e) {
    print(d) // Hello .
}
```

You might want to choose better function names and i hope this work.

Comment: Thanks, you given me a light with this, the final solution was encodeURI(string) when it send and decodeURI(string) when it go to store in MongoDB